# Blazor WebAssembly getting a "memory access out of bounds error" when returning an image from JSInterop call

Tags: javascript, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly, blazor-jsinterop

I have a Blazor WebAssembly application capturing video from the computer webcam. The video Element linked to the webcam is hidden. The Video feed is painted to an HTML canvas element.

I am using JSInterop to call GetImageData() on the canvas. The function returns an image of part of the canvas as an image.

When I return the image from the JavaScript function I get a:

"dotnet.wasm:1 Uncaught (in promise) RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds error"

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <video id="videoElement" @ref="VideoElement" autoplay="true" width="1280" height="720"></video>
    <canvas id="videoCanvas" @ref="VideoCanvas" width="1280" height="720"></canvas>
</div>
```

Here is the code causing the issue. I've narrowed it down to the line in OnTimedEvent:

```
@code {
    ElementReference VideoElement;
    ElementReference VideoCanvas;

    protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("StartVideo", VideoElement);
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("PaintVideoToCanvas", VideoElement, VideoCanvas);

        Timer _timer = new Timer(5000);
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private async void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {    
        Image temp = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<Image>("ImageScanner", VideoCanvas);
    }
}
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function StartVideo(VideoElement) {

    let video = VideoElement;

    if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { width: { min: 1280 }, height: { min: 720 } } })
            .then(function (stream) {
                video.srcObject = stream;
            })
            .catch(function (err0r) {
                console.log("Something went wrong!");
            });
    }
}

function PaintVideoToCanvas(VideoElement, VideoCanvas) {

    let video = VideoElement;
    let canvas = VideoCanvas;

    let ctxLayer1 = canvas.getContext("2d");
    StartVideo();

    function StartVideo() {
        ctxLayer1.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
        setTimeout(StartVideo, 1000 / 30); // drawing at 30fps
    }
}

function ImageScanner(VideoCanvas) {

    let video = VideoCanvas;

    let ctxQRCapture = video.getContext("2d");

    let image = ctxQRCapture.getImageData(950, 260, 200, 200);

    return image;
}
```

Comment: It look like is not possible pass argument more than 1.3mb. Have you found any solution?